# Searching a list that contains a certain int from another list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I find myself in a need to create a new list that has certain properties on a given list.

For example, I have this list:

```
List<string> aStringList = new List<string>() {
                                                "meat1", "meat2",
                                                "tomato3", "tomatoes4",
                                                "brocolli5", "brocoli6"
                                               };
```

Then with a given parameter of

```
List<int> aIntList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 6 };
```

I need to generate a new list that contains only
*meat1, meat2, brocoli6*.

I know that I can use this:

```
 var matchingvalues = aStringList.Where(s => s.Contains(aIntList [0].ToString())
                                          || s.Contains(aIntList [1].ToString())
                                          || s.Contains(aIntList [2].ToString())
                                        );
```

But it’s ugly and it’s not dynamic.

How else can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not fully clear what `aIntList` contains. If it contains indexes then the answer by @dmitry-bychenko is good. But if the second list contains part of content then you could use this approach:

```
List<string> aStringList = new List<string>() {
    "meat1", "meat2",
    "tomato3", "tomatoes4",
    "brocolli5", "brocoli6"
};

List<int> aIntList = new List<int>() { 1, 6, 2 };

var matchingvalues = aStringList.Where(s => aIntList.Any(a=>s.Contains(a.ToString())));
```

It allows you to avoid explicit iteration in the `Where` condition.

Another way is to use `Join`, but it requires parsing the string first. It could look like this:

```
var matchingvalues2 = aStringList.Join(
    aIntList,
    s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value),
    i => i,
    (s, i) => s
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can *query* an existing list with the help of [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-where-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-system-boolean)))) which can accept both `value` and `index`:

```
List<string> aStringList = new List<string>() {
  "meat1", "meat2",
  "tomato3", "tomatoes4",
  "brocolli5", "brocoli6"
};

List<int> aIntList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 6 };

// Please, note Where syntax:
// we accept all values but filter by index
var matchingvalues = aStringList
  .Where((value, index) => aIntList.Contains(index + 1))
  .ToList(); // Let's have a list as a result
```

Another possibility is to query `aIntList`: for each `index` within `aIntList` we return the corresponding item from `aStringList`:

```
var matchingvalues = aIntList
  .Where(index >= 1 && index <= aStringList.Count)
  .Select(index => aStringList[index - 1])
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any`:

```
var matchingvalues = aStringList.Where(s => 
    aIntList.Any(i =>
        s.Contains(i.ToString())
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> aStringList 
            = new List<string>() {
                "meat1", "meat2",
                "tomato3", "tomatoes4",
                "brocolli5", "brocoli6" };

        List<int> aIntList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 6 };

        List<string> matchingvalues 
            = aIntList.Select((index) => aStringList[index-1]).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", matchingvalues));
        // meat1, meat2, brocoli6
    }
}
```

No need for `.Where()` or `.Containts()` or anything like that. Use the array `aIntList` to pull the values you want directly out of `aStringList`.